# How to click on the Browse Button

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to upload a file, but prior to that, I need to click on the Browse button. I have tried every possible way that I can think of, but no luck.  I get an error "unable to locate element".

This is the page HTML

```
<div class="file_input_div">
<input type="button" value="Browse" class="file_input_button">
<input type="file" style="width:100px;" onchange="javascript: document.getElementById('fileName').value = this.value" value="" size="25" name="theFile">
```

My code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
//wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("theFile")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("theFile")));
driver.findElement(By.name("theFile")).click();
```

Comment: Why do you want o `click()`?

Comment: To Browse out to the folder location...

Comment: use sendKeys when type of inpput is file. Clicking on browse will open os specific dialog that webdriver wont be able to interact...

Comment: simply `driver.findElement(By.name("theFile")).sendKeys("FilepathWithExtension" )` should do it

Comment: The text field next to the Browse button is "read only", hence can not send url either...

Comment: There is no click needed with `WebDriver` api to upload a file. Direct use of `sendKeys()` should be enough

Comment: text field or input field?

Comment: And if sendKeys doesnt works use JavascriptExecutor followed by onchange value given in tag...

Comment: And one more tip, wait.until statement will return you that element itself. So again execution of findElement is not required. SImply save that element in WebElement for future reference or append your statement with click or sendKeys or whatever operation you require to provide... :)

Comment: is this correct js:    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
 js.executeScript("document.getElementById('fileName').click();");

Comment: yup but why click()? simply perform as told by @Saifur or `js.executeScript("document.getElementById('fileName').value="+yourPath);`

Comment: I tried the following, but getting error "WebDriverException: missing ; before statement.   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
 js.executeScript("document.getElementById('fileName').value=" + swf_creative);

Comment: `js.executeScript("document.getElementById('fileName').value=\"" + swf_creative+"\"");` can u try out with this?

Comment: sorry, Vivek...getting this error now.... document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71207/discussion-between-vivek-singh-and-familyguy).

Comment: As suggested by Saifur JS works fine!. As suggested by Vivek, it was missing the iframe. The following code works... driver.switchTo().frame("sUpload");
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
 js.executeScript("document.getElementById('fileName').value=\"" + swf_creative+"\"");